# .includes() Is always returning true

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Wordle type game, I have started on the basics where it is just using the console to tell me weather the letters are correct or not. In the function check letter the first if statement works flawlessly but on the second one when it is checking weather or not the guess and the word both have the same letter just not in the correct spot. But even when the letter is not even in both of the variable it will console "wrong spot" instead of "wrong letter".

```
const word = "Lucas";
let guessed = prompt("Please Guess The Word");
checkLength()

function checkLength() {
  if (word.length == guessed.length) {
    console.log("It Worked")
    checkLetter(0)
    checkLetter(1)
    checkLetter(2)
    checkLetter(3)
    checkLetter(4)
  } else {
    console.log("It Failed")
    guessed = prompt("Please Use 5 Letters");
  }
}

function checkLetter(letterPos) {
  if (word.charAt(letterPos) == guessed.charAt(letterPos)) {
    console.log("Same Letter! " + letterPos)
  } else {
    let letterW = word.charAt(letterPos)
    let letterG = guessed.charAt(letterPos)
    if (word.includes(letterW) == guessed.includes(letterG)) {
      console.log("Wrong Spot " + letterPos)
    } else {
      console.log("Wrong Letter " + letterPos)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if the letter is not in both variables, both includes will return false, and false==false is actually true. so it will print wrong spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we should clean up the variables. Then, all that needs fixing is the second if statement. We want to check if `letterG` exists in `word`, if not, then it's the wrong letter.

```js
function checkLetter(letterPos) {
  let letterW = word.charAt(letterPos);
  let letterG = guessed.charAt(letterPos);

  if (letterW == letterG) {
    console.log("Same Letter! " + letterPos)
  } else if (word.includes(letterG)) {
    console.log("Wrong Spot " + letterPos)
  } else {
    console.log("Wrong Letter " + letterPos)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `includes` returns `true` or `false`, not the index, so when both `world` and `guessed` don't include the letter, `false == false` would return `true`:

```
if (letterG !== letterw && word.includes(letterW))
```

The above condition should work.

Comment: This also works but the answer I marked correct way just simpler, but thanks for explaining it to me!